# How to avoid getting a deleted instance passed to merge on a One To Many relationship with Set?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have this mapping in a Hibernate entity.

A.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
Set<B> bs;
```

B.java

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
A a;
```

I need to perform an edit on A.

So after loading the entity in a method annotated with `Spring @Transactional`

```
A a = entityManager.find(A.class, a.getId);
// set some new values on the instance variables of a.

// take out the set of Bs through a and delete them
for(B b : a.getBs()) {
    entityManager.remove(b);
}

// create new objects of B and add them to the below set-
Set<B> bs = new HashSet<>();
a.setBs(bs);

entityManager.merge(a);
```

The above code is part of a **single method**.

I get - deleted instance passed to merge.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` in class `B`. So while doing `entityManager.remove(b)` the remove operation is cascading and removing `a`.

You can do something like this in `B` according to your necessity:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
```

Comment: Looks Great. Will check, test and then will come back to you if it works.